# For a ball rotating at an angle to forward motion, how to determine the friction vector?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Would appreciate any help -- I appears to be getting my right-hand and left-hand mixed.

Let's the ball moving in the positive x-axis, so its initial velocity $\vec{v}$ is (v<sub>x</sub>, 0, 0) and it's rotating in the direction of motion, would its rotation vector $\vec{\omega}$ be (0, $\omega$<sub>y</sub>, 0)?

And its tangential velocity $\vec{w}$<sub>$\perp$</sub> = $\vec{\omega}$ x $\vec{r}$ = (0, $\omega$<sub>y</sub>, 0) x (0, 0, -r) = (-r$\omega$<sub>y</sub>, 0, 0) ?

Assuming it's rolling with slipping, so $\vec{v}$  > $\vec{w}$<sub>$\perp$</sub>, would the friction vector be in the direction of $\vec{s}$ = $\vec{\omega}$ x $\vec{r}$ - $\vec{v}$ = (-r$\omega$<sub>y</sub> - v<sub>x</sub>, 0, 0)? eg let $\hat{s}$ = $\vec{s}$/$\lvert$s$\rvert$, then $\vec{F}$<sub>friction</sub> = $\mu$mg$\hat{s}$ = $\mu$mg(-r$\omega$<sub>y</sub> - v<sub>x</sub>, 0, 0)/$\lvert$s$\rvert$.

The angular accelaration $\alpha$ = I<sup>-1</sup>$\tau$ = I<sup>-1</sup>$\vec{r}$ x$\vec{F}$<sub>friction</sub> = I<sup>-1</sup> (0, 0, -r) x $\mu$mg(-r$\omega$<sub>y</sub> - v<sub>x</sub>, 0, 0)/$\lvert$s$\rvert$ = (I<sup>-1</sup>$\mu$mg/$\lvert$s$\rvert$) (0, r(r$\omega$<sub>y</sub> + v<sub>x</sub>), 0)?
The friction force slows the ball down and increases the rotation?

---

Now, let's say the ball is rotating in the y-axis. Would its rotation vector $\vec{\omega}$ be (-$\omega$<sub>x</sub>, 0, 0)? Thus its tangential velocity $\vec{w}$<sub>$\perp$</sub> = $\vec{\omega}$ x $\vec{r}$ = (-$\omega$<sub>x</sub>, 0, 0) x (0, 0, -r) = (0, -r$\omega$<sub>y</sub>, 0) ?

The direction of the friction would be $\vec{s}$ = $\vec{\omega}$ x $\vec{r}$ - $\vec{v}$ = (-v<sub>x</sub>, -r$\omega$<sub>y</sub>, 0)?

This doesn't make sense to me. The frictional force would deflect the ball in the negative y-axis when I'm expecting it to deflect in the positive y-axis.

Where did I get my right/left hand mixed up?

Is the mistake in assuming the condition for slipping vs skidding has to be component wise? eg The condition should be s<sub>i</sub> = w<sub>$\perp$</sub><sub>i</sub> - v<sub>i</sub> only if v<sub>i</sub> > w<sub>$\perp$</sub><sub>i</sub>, otherwise s<sub>i</sub> = v<sub>i</sub> - w<sub>$\perp$</sub><sub>i</sub> if  v<sub>i</sub> < w<sub>$\perp$</sub><sub>i</sub>, for i in x & y?

Comment: Friction opposes relative motion of the surfaces in contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I made a little diagram to work out what is positive or not

[image: fig1]

Where $+x$ is to the right, $+y$ is into the plane, and $+z$ is up. This is a right-hand coordinate system. The ball moves along $+x$ and also rotates about $+y$.

> Is friction, as shown, acting along $-x$ on the ball, and $+x$ on the ground? Or is the other way around?

**Friction opposes relative motion.** So the answer is it depends on the slip velocity.

The rotational velocity of the ball is $$\vec{\omega} = \pmatrix{0 \\ \omega_z \\ 0}$$ because if you point your right-hand thumb into the plane, your fingers point to a clockwise rotation. This is the right-hand rule in action here.

The translational velocity of the center **C** is by the problem definition $$\vec{v}_C = \pmatrix{v_x \\ 0 \\ 0}$$

If the ball has radius $R$, then the velocity of the contact point **A** is $$\vec{v}_A = \vec{v}_C + (\vec{r}_C-\vec{r}_A) \times \vec{\omega} = \pmatrix{v_x \\ 0 \\ 0} + \pmatrix{ 0 \\ 0 \\ R} \times \pmatrix{0 \\ \omega_y \\ 0} = \pmatrix{v_x - R\, \omega_y \\ 0 \\ 0} $$

Since the ground does not move, we say the slip velocity is $$ v_{\rm slip} = v_x - R\, \omega_y $$

So if slip velocity is positive $v_x > R \, \omega_y$, friction is acting in the $-x$ axis, as shown above. And if $v_x < R \, \omega_y$, then friction is acting in the $+x$ direction.

The friction force vector, given a known magnitude $F=\mu N$ is

$$ \vec{F} = \pmatrix{F_x \\ 0 \\ 0 } = - {\rm sign}(v_x - R\, \omega_y) \pmatrix{F \\ 0 \\ 0} $$

where $\rm sign()$ is a function returning +1 if the argument is positive, -1 if negative and 0 if zero.

The above can be used in the equations of motion

$$ \vec{F} - m g \hat{z} + \vec{N} = m \vec{a}_C $$ but since the contact normal force counteracts gravity, you have $\vec{F} = m \vec{a}_C$. Now remember that $F_x =-\mathrm{sign}(v_x-R\,\omega_y) F$ from above, so the linear acceleration is found with

$$ -\mathrm{sign}(v_x-R\,\omega_y) F = m \dot{v}_x $$

And rotationally, look at the torque at the center of mass

$$ \vec{\tau}_C = (\vec{r}_A - \vec{r}_C) \times \vec{F} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ -R} \times \pmatrix{F_x \\ 0 \\ 0} = \pmatrix{0 \\ -R\,F_x \\ 0}  $$

And the rotational acceleration $$\vec{\alpha} = \pmatrix{0 \\ \dot{\omega}_y \\ 0}$$ to arrive at the rotational acceleration.

$$ \mathrm{sign}(v_x-R\,\omega_y) F\,R = I_{\rm yy} \dot{\omega}_y $$

Comment: Ah. Thank you. For the relative motion, the radial vector is as seen from the contact point, so it is pointing from the ground to the center of the ball, not from the ball center to the ground.

But for the torque, the slippage force rotate the ball, so the vector is from the center of the ball to the contact point.

Comment: The transformation of velocity is similar to the transformation of torque $$\begin{aligned}\vec{v}_{A} & =\vec{v}_{C}+(\vec{r}_{C}-\vec{r}_{A})\times\vec{\omega}\\
\vec{\tau}_{A} & =\vec{\tau}_{C}+(\vec{r}_{C}-\vec{r}_{A})\times\vec{F}
\end{aligned}$$